# Markov Chain Expected value

Tags: markov-chains, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a Markov chain with State space $E=\{1,2,3\}$ and transission matrix

$$P=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1/3 & 2/3 \\        1/4 & 3/4 & 0 \\ 2/5 & 0 & 3/5     \end{bmatrix}$$

How can I compute $E[X_{n+1}^3|X_n=j]$, for $j=1,2,3$.

Comment: Looks like there's an error in your matrix as the rows should sum to $1$

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it!

Comment: Just expand *Expected value* definition and as you know the condintional probability distribution function, you'll finish it :
$$E[X_{n+1}^3|X_n=1]=\sum_{X_{n+1}=1}^3 X_{n+1}^3.P(X_{n+1}|X_n=1)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just calculate it? For example,

$E[X_{n+1}^3 | X_n = 1] $

$= 1^3.Pr(X_{n+1} = 1 | X_n = 1) +  2^3.Pr(X_{n+1} = 2 | X_n = 1) +  3^3.Pr(X_{n+1} = 3 | X_n = 1)$

$ = 1 \cdot 0 + 8 \cdot (1/3) + 27 \cdot (2/3) $

$ = ...$

Comment: Thanks, I was just not sure how to handle the power of 3.